# Using R, how do I find duplicates and output them?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use R to find duplicate values, and then merge them into the same row.

Please see my code below:

#Attempt to select duplicates and merge into 1 row with mrn and alternate mrn

##line 1

```
duplicates <- combined.csv2 %>% group_by(variable_tcc_id) %>% mutate(num_dups = n(), dup_id = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(consent_notes = ifelse(dup_id > 1, paste0(consent_location,' ','MRN:',mrn), consent_notes))
```

##line 2

```
duplicates2 <- duplicates %>% mutate(consent_notes = ifelse(num_dups > 1 & dup_id == '1', paste0('Other MRNs:',consent_notes), consent_notes))
```

##line 3

```
duplicates2$consent_notes <- sub("2 MRN", "LAC MRN", duplicates2$consent_notes)
```

##line 4

```
duplicates2$consent_notes <- sub("4 MRN", "Outside MRN", duplicates2$consent_notes)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Speaking of duplication as a phenomenon… Did you look at prior SO questions on this topic?

Comment: I did but couldn't find any that relates to this.